# Whats the Min and Max temperature of an ATI Raedon HD 5800 series?

Tags: graphics-card, amd-radeon, temperature

I am having heat problems with my **ATI Radeon HD 5800 series card**, the **minimum temperature of my card is 45C and max I have had it at was 90C**. Do I have a heat problem or is this the temperature the card tends to get up to? (I have cleaned out my computer). I am a bit concerned because these temperature seems high.

Comment: Which graphics card do you have?

Comment: Right I cleaned my PC out and cleaned each fan with Prussurised air the card seem to be stable at 64C when playing minecraft for 2 1/2 hours. before it was 90C in about 4 hours, I think this may have improved it.

Comment: @Gilly That sounds better. Be sure to accept an answer (or post yours as one and accept it) when you feel that your problem is resolved. :)

Answer (score 4):

I've heard it stated that you don't want to get your GPU above 70 degrees Celsius or so, and that even in the 60s you're starting to push it. At that point, you may start to do damage to the card itself. I don't know about minimum temps but the 40s are fine for operating temperatures.

I would start re-evaluating my cooling strategy if I'm going over mid-60s regularly.

Having it up in the 90s is out of the picture. That's way too high of a temperature to be considered safe. You'll likely cause permanent damage or shorten the life of the card with such high temps.

Answer (score 2):

According to some of the links I am looking at that seems about proper for an average card. The peak may be a bit on the high side but the low is normal. Those temperatures shouldn't cause any issues with the cards. Although a bit better(Read: not necessarily more) air flow in your case could help your issue.

[AMD Blog](http://blogs.amd.com/play/2009/09/22/ati-radeon-hd-5800-series-graphics-cards-designed-by-the-community/)

[Tom's Hardware Forum](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/276943-33-radeon-5850-normal-temps-underload)

Answer (score 0):

I have had a 5800 since it came out. I'm running it with a first gen i7 on an MSI board. I have noticed in the years that the card heats up faster than when I first had it. The fan goes to about 80% any time a game is running. When idle, it is at 67c. With a game it is at 90c+.

My point of this, is that this card is a beast, and survives an average of 70c-90c every day for 2-4 hours a day.

Answer (score -1):

There is a maximum temperature at which any device with a core or a clock can function at, but it is very different for minimum temperatures.

For example, a company had a nitrogen cooled CPU. It was cooled to almost -200°C – that's cold. And as a result they were able to overclock it to insane amounts. If I remember correctly, they clocked the CPU from 1 GHz to 6 GHz. Colder is better for cores, but not for your system temperature.